# wpf execution time error, color resource not found

Tags: wpf, material-design

This is my App.xaml conf

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Goldenrod.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DataGrid.xaml" />
```

with that I receive this error:
cannot locate resource  'themes/recommended/primary/materialdesigncolor.goldenrod.xaml'

But if I change Goldenrod by Blue then everything works fine, I also can use Goldenrod as foreground in my  Views etc.
The problem happens if try to use it as Primary in my Theme

Comment: Do you do have that file locally?

Comment: It's telling you the file isn"t there. Goldenrod is a standard wpf named color and brush so you can set a color or brush to goldenrod.